# Extracting XML Child Elements Where the Parents are in a Defaulted Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have the below XML and I've been trying to extract the FirstName, LastName and OtherName for a while now I'm running into all sort of problems.

```
<OmdCds xmlns="cds"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:cdsd="cds_dt"
        xsi:schemaLocation="cds ontariomd_cds.xsd">   
  <PatientRecord>
    <Demographics>
      <Names>
        <cdsd:LegalName namePurpose="L">
          <cdsd:FirstName>
            <cdsd:Part>SARAH</cdsd:Part>
            <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
            <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</cdsd:PartQualifier>
          </cdsd:FirstName>
          <cdsd:LastName>
            <cdsd:Part>GOMEZ</cdsd:Part>
            <cdsd:PartType>FAMC</cdsd:PartType>
            <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</cdsd:PartQualifier>
          </cdsd:LastName>
          <cdsd:OtherName>
            <cdsd:Part>GABRIELA</cdsd:Part>
            <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
            <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</PartQualifier>
```

I currently trying to extract with the below c# code but still can't extract the above data. I'm getting a nullreferenceexception.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(folder + "\\" + o.ToString());
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cdsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XmlNode firstName = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/PatientRecord/Demographics/Names/cdsd:LegalName/cdsd:FirstName/cdsd:Part", namespaceManager);
string fName = firstName.InnerText;
MessageBox.Show(fName);
```

I can see in the local watch item under doc.DocumentElement, all the InnerXML and InnerText. The InnerXML look something like this...

```
  <PatientRecord xmlns=\"cds\"><Demographics><Names><cdsd:LegalName namePurpose=\"L\" xmlns:cdsd=\"cds_dt\"><cdsd:FirstName><cdsd:Part>SARAH</cdsd:Part><cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType><cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</cdsd:PartQualifier></cdsd:FirstName>
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument? Using LINQ to XML generally makes it much simpler to handle namespaces. Additionally, if you could pay a bit more attention to formatting your code and sample XML pleasantly in the future, it would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Can you try the xpath without namespace? XmlNode firstName = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/PatientRecord/Demographics/Names/LegalName/FirstName/Part");

Comment: Many of the answers here miss one key character to their xPath.  The xPath start like this "./cds:PatientRecord/ - The  miss the period which was driving me  nuts until I was doing some reading and  realizing that the period(.) was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 namespace definitions in the document:

- `cds` - as a default namespace
- `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`- with the `xsi` prefix
- `cds_dt` - with the `cdsd` prefix

I am wondering that you don't get an error message, because `cds` and `cds_dt` are no URIs and namspaces need to be URIs.

If you try to understand an element name you need to replaces the prefix with the actual namespace.

- `<PatientRecord>` reads as `{cds}:PatientRecord`
- `<cdsd:LegalName>` reads as `{cds_dt}:LegalName`

Now in XPath 1.0 the same happens with registered namespaces. But XPath does not have a default namespace. So elements without one are not expanded with a default namespace.

You need to register namespace prefixes on the namespace manager. The prefix does not need to be the same as in the document.

```
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cdsd", "cds_dt");
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cds", "cds");
```

Now you can use the registered namespaces in XPath:

```
doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(
  "cds:PatientRecord/cds:Demographics/cds:Names/cdsd:LegalName/cdsd:FirstName/cdsd:Part",
  namespaceManager
);
```

If the first character of an XPath expression is a slash the expression is relative to the document, otherwise to the current context node. You call `SelectSingleNode()` on the `doc.DocumentElement` - the `OmdCds` element node. `PatientRecord` is a child node, so you can start with it or use `.` for the current context node.

Comment: Just had to add the period at the starting of  the  XPath. EG: "./cds:PatientRecord/cds....."

Comment: Actually you can just remove the /. I updated the answer and added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`PatientRecord`, `Demographics` and `Names` are in the `cds` namespace. This is because of the default namespace declaration on the `OmdCds` element (`xmlns="cds"`). The others are in the `cdsd` namespace, not `xsi`. You'll have to add them and use them in the XPATH:

```
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cdsd", "cdsd");
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cds", "cds");
XmlNode firstName = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(
    "/cds:PatientRecord/cds:Demographics/cds:Names/cdsd:LegalName/cdsd:FirstName/cdsd:Part",
    namespaceManager);
```

BTW, you're getting a `NullReferenceException` because you're making the false assumption that your query will always return a node. You are now seeing what happens when it does not return a node. Always check for `null` whenever it's possible that a query returns no value.

Answer (score -1):

Instead XmlDocument class you can use Linq to XML, is easy. You need using the System.Xml.Linq namspace, for example:

```
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("path");
            IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = (from p in xdoc.Descendants()
                                           where p.Name.LocalName == "FirstName"
                                           select p).Elements();

            foreach (XElement nodeFirstName in nodes)
            {
                foreach (XElement parts in nodeFirstName.Elements())
                {
                  string strExtracted = parts.Name.LocalName + " " + parts.Value;
                }
            }
```

The LocalName property is used beacuse elements have a prefix "cdsd"

Comment: You should learn to use namespaces instead of using local names.

Comment: John and as you know that I don't know how use it?. I am giving a quick and viable response to the problem. Please, pay attention.

Comment: He prestado atención. Usted le dio ninguna indicación de que usted sabe cómo usarlos. Si usted sabe cómo usarlos, muestran en su respuesta. BTW, aqui se habla Inglés.

Comment: I am new commenting on StackOverflow, and my perception of this forum is that it should help people solve any problems and provide resolution options, but not to pretend to be the Master of the Universe. That's all my dear friend.

Comment: I've been on this site a bit longer than you. And, BTW, it's not a forum.